# Comment visibility

Tags: comments

There will be many people commenting on a post. So, when a commentator visits the post, he should be able to see 'only' his own comment(s).Post author can see all comments only on his own post.

How can I do this in WordPress?

Answer (score 4):

By using the 'pre_get_comments' action, found in `wp-includes/comment.php`:

```
function restrict_visible_comments( $comments_query ) {
    if ( !is_singular() )
        return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'moderate_comments' ) )
        return;  // moderators can see all comments

    if ( get_current_user_id() == get_queried_object()->post_author )
        return;  // the author of the post can see all comments

    $comments_query->query_vars['user_id'] = get_current_user_id();
}
if ( !is_admin() )
    add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'restrict_visible_comments' );
```

Note that the above won't display comments left by non-registered users.

**Update:** Nevermind, this won't work because get_comments() isn't used consistently in comments_template():

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L882

Comment: Can you please post some more details.

Comment: I would like some more info about this too

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: @scribu Thanks for the code. It works great except that it doesn't fulfill this condition, "when a commentator visits the post, he should be able to see 'only' his own comment(s)" assuming that he is not post author or admin. Can you please help? And also all users are registered, so that is not a problem.

Comment: I am using Members plugin by Justin Tadlock if it has something to do with the $comments_query->query_vars['user_id'] = get_current_user_id(); line not working.

Comment: @scribu don't you need to return the `$comments_query` variable, whether modified or not? (i.e. `return $comments_query;` rather than merely `return;`) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chip Bennett: No, because 'pre_get_comments' is an action. Corrected code.

Comment: @scribu oops, I was thinking of `pre_process_comment`. I'm going to go have some coffee before reading any more WPSE questions/answers this morning!

Comment: @AgentWP: See updated answer.

Comment: @scribu mentioned `get_comments()` is used inconsistently in `comments_template()` in an update to his answer. I believe this is now fixed (see changeset [29965](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/29965))

Answer (score 0):

use the comments_array filter, and remove the unnecessary comments.

Some loose code to get you started

```
<?php
add_filter('comments_array','display_only_user_comments')
function display_only_user_comments($comments){
    $comemnts=NULL;
    /*modify this part to get only user comments*/
    if ( $user_ID) {
              $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND (comment_approved = '1' OR ( user_id = %d AND comment_approved = '0' ) )  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, $user_ID));
        } else if ( empty($comment_author) ) {
                $comments = get_comments( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'approve', 'order' => 'ASC') );
       } else {
                $comments = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d AND ( comment_approved = '1' OR ( comment_author = %s AND comment_author_email = %s AND comment_approved = '0' ) ) ORDER BY comment_date_gmt", $post->ID, wp_specialchars_decode($comment_author,ENT_QUOTES), $comment_author_email));

    }

    return $comments;
}
?>
```

Comment: Because `$comments` are actual array of comments, I think you should not use raw SQL queries to get them again. Instead of that, you can loop the `$comments` and `unset()` not matched comments.

Answer (score 0):

@Satish... Thanks a lot man! I don't know if you're solution worked for the question asker, but it worked for me! I has spent 2 days trying things with 'comments_clauses' and 'pre_get_comments', and had given up!

Answer (score 0):

My solution for author to see only his comments

```
add_filter('pre_get_comments','display_only_user_comments');
function display_only_user_comments($query){
    global $pagenow;
    if('edit-comments.php' != $pagenow || $query->is_admin)
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->query_vars['post_author'] = $user_ID;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Useful Comments Plugin](http://mashable.com/2007/07/24/wordpress-comments/)..If you are not well known about codings means Plugin is the Easiest Way to Do that.:) I hope you got answer...:)

Comment: None of the plugin is useful there.

Comment: thanks for your negative vote:).Really it's help to Increase Answering the questions...

Comment: I did not vote for you man!